# Fighting stance in Boxing and MMA, requires hunch and curved back position

Tags: technique, mixed-martial-arts, boxing, muay-thai

This might be a slightly odd question. Does boxing, Muay thai, and MMA build bad posture eventually? I noticed after long periods of time, training 2 hours a day, 4-5 times a week, the back is not placed in a straight, good upright position. These fighting sports require a very slight hunch in shoulders upper back, to prevent blows, but also causes wear, tear, and exhaustion for me in this position. See the hunch below.

When I play basketball or flag football, my back is a straight upright position, whether it be diagonal and my knees are bent. Karate has less of this issue. Curious if anyone has any thoughts or way to alleviate this issue?

**Boxing and MMA:**

[image]

[image]

**Karate: (more upright and straight)**

[image]

**Basketball:**

(even when knees bent, back diagonal is generally straighter than fighting sports)

[image]

Comment: Hmm... this is outside of my wheelhouse, but doing a quick Google search, the general tenor of remarks is that good boxing posture involves a straight neutral spine and loose shoulders. The only forward bend is tucking the chin.

Comment: Hi @MacacoBranco I see a Lot majority of boxers and ufc round their shoulders and back, Mayweather and pictures above,  not sure why, probably offers better protection ina shell hunch position. Thanks

Comment: I'll look at maybe posting something more substantive tonight, but https://www.getphysical.com/blog/fighter-posture describes more of what goes into this. Some of it is muscular development, some of it is bad training, but boxing and MMA should not be teaching people to largely be hunched up.